# How can I add on this JavaScript function auto sliding?

Tags: javascript, slider

How can I add auto sliding? I tried with setTimeout but not working.

```
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("slide");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
```

Someone can help me with a solution? Thank you vert much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the **setInterval()** function instead of the `setTimeout()` function

> https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval

The **setTimeout()** function execute only one time your function after 2 seconds.

> https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout

## (Really) Basic implementation

Replace this

```
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);
```

By this

```
var slideIndex = 1;
setInterval(function() {
    slideIndex++;
    showSlides(slideIndex);
}, 2000)
```

Comment: Thank you!  But how can I integrate on my script?

Comment: @CraitaGeorgeAdelin I have edited with a basic implentation.

Comment: Thank you so much! Working but now is a little bug. When I access the page the slide not showing I need to wait 2 seconds and start directly with the second slide.

Comment: All work in properly now! I moved at the bottom your function! Thank's !!

Comment: @CraitaGeorgeAdelin Great then! Feel free to accept my post as the answer :-)